# mybase.load stops loading when calling a function vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function

I step through this code and find out that the function is not only never called but the rest of the myBase.Load never completes what is going on here.

All outside references are displayed now. Program never hits the lines surrounded in **  and does run frmMain_Load as first item.  the stepthrough icon does land ON the line that starts with reader= but never calls runAsIsQuery (breakpoints don't catch and stepthrough just evaporates). then it shows me frmMain without proccessing any other code from frmMain_Load nor from runAsISQuery

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sqlstring = "SELECT Nickname FROM tblBikeInfo"
    reader = sql.runAsIsQuery(cnn, sqlstring) 'never fires
    **If 1 = 1 Then**
        'ummmm never comes back here either
    End If
```

Extra details asked for about the other references  these are in frmMain as global vars

```
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
Dim sql As OLEDB_Handling  'custom  class
Public cnn = MotorcyleDB.GetConnection
```

Function from Custom Class (OLEDB_Handling)

```
**Public Function runAsIsQuery(connection As OleDbConnection, SQL As String) As OleDbDataReader**
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(SQL)
    command.Connection = connection
    Try
        connection.Open()
        reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Return reader

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

Connection string class called (MotorcyleDB)

```
Public Shared Function GetConnection() As OleDbConnection

    Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\************\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MotorcycleMinder\MotorcycleMinder\MotorcycleServiceLog11.accdb")
End Function
```

Comment: you need to provide a lot more than this for us to know. How is reader created, how is sql created, how is cnn created, what happends if the code is placed in a try catch block? Have you  tried running the query with just RunQuery?

Comment: The line that tries to call runAsIsQuery is generating an exception. Because you have no exception handling there it is exiting.  Either put a Try..Catch around it to catch the exception, or change the Break On setting for the debugger.

Comment: well i had oledbexcpetion catch on my local copy and it seems that it wasn't enough. now that i put a generic catch it does actaully catch... and NOW i get null ref exception.. which i can handle.. well lesson learned.  and now i can show this to an old teacher of mine that i asked for help on (who couldn't answer it either)  thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this: 
http://blog.adamjcooper.com/2011/05/why-is-my-exception-being-swallowed-in.html

This is a snippet from the site.

> If these conditions are met:
>
> 1. You are running on a 64-bit version of Windows (whether your application is built for 32-bit or 64-bit doesn’t matter; only the bit
>      depth of the OS)
> 2. You are building a WinForms app
> 3. You are debugging the application with Visual Studio (using default
>      options for Exception catching)
> 4. Your main form has a Load event handler
> 5. During the execution of your Load handler, an exception occurs
>
> Then:
>
> The exception will be silently swallowed by the system and, while your
>   handler will not continue execution, your application will continue
>   running.If you wrap your handler code in a try/catch block, you can
>   still explicitly catch any thrown exceptions. But if you don’t, you’ll
>   never know anything went wrong.
>
> Note that all of the conditions must be met. If, for instance, you run
>   the application without debugging, then an unhandled exception still
>   be correctly thrown.

There is also a workaround on the site. But I would put the code in a try catch block, or put the entire thing in the Initializer/Constructor.

Comment: WozzeC is correct.  Here is another discussion on the subject http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/a0016d16-9fac-4bd8-88de-b2959b1827e9

Comment: I went ahead and put the function call into a trycatch block and still nothing happened. I know that there is no error in the function because while using F8 to step through the Load even, the function is never called it just stops and acts like it's done with frmMain_Load.  I'll go ahead and read the site but just for reference, the function itself is never touched.  i'll go ahead and populate all references into my question but then you'll have to let me in on the secret of how uncalled code can effect anything :)

Comment: @WozzeC Question is updated with the code you asked for and I've added more details to hopefully show why I believe it can't be an exception (unless you can some how cause an exception by calling a function that exists in a different class... but how would i put a trycatch around that? )

Comment: To specify the answer for anyone else that sees this.  always do an exception check of the generic exception type, even if you already have other excpetion checking included..  less you want to look as foolish as I did here :)